# Inset disappears when rotated in presence of a density plot

Tags: graphics, text, rotation, inset

Notice that the rotated "Hi" does not show up (MacOS, Mathematica 12.0). If you remove the `DensityPlot`, then it does.

```
Show[DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[.6 + .4 #] &)],
 Graphics[{
   Inset[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 140], {0, 0}],
   Rotate[Inset[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 140], {0, 0}], .5]
   }]
 ]
```

Is this a bug or a feature? And is there a workaround?

[image]

A simpler example to reproduce the same:

```
Graphics[{
    Polygon[{{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}},VertexColors->{Yellow, Blue, Yellow}],
    Inset[Style["Hi",FontSize->140],{0,0}],
    Rotate[Inset[Style["Hi",FontSize->140],{0,0}],.5]
}]
```

Comment: In the first sentence I think that you meant DensityPlot rather then Display Plot. I will remove this comment in a day or two.

Comment: This works for me in both Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1 on macOS.

Comment: I can reproduce it with 12.0.0 on macOS, but not with 12.1. I will go ahead and edit a smaller example into your post. Please edit as you see fit afterwards.

Comment: Having a Polygon with VertexColors triggers a different rendering mode akin to 3D graphics (there are subtle sign if you look carefully). DensityPlot has such polygons.

Comment: @user6014 I use a MBP with dual graphics. It turns out that I can reproduce this only if I restrict it to use the integrated (Intel) graphics. With the Radeon 560 it works correctly.